# React.js setState does not update state even if render method was called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I cannot believe that I cannot update state by setState.
I want to update cardModalOpen state to close the Modal.

I add bind(this) but it still does not work.

(Modal is opened by click Card Component)

However, I  did `setState({cardModalOpen: false})` by `closeModal()` function but it is still true even after render method was called.

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong.

This is my code.

index.js

```
import React, { Component }from 'react';
import { Button, Card, Image, Header, Modal, Form, Input } from 'semantic-ui-react'

class App extends React.Component {    
    state = { cardModalOpen:false }

    showCardModal() {
        this.setState({cardModalOpen:true})    
    }

    closeModal(){
        this.setState({cardModalOpen:false})
    }

    render() {
        const messagesDataNew = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            messagesDataNew.push(
              <Card
                onClick={() => {
                  this.showCardModal();
                }}
              >
                <DetailModal
                  cardModalOpen={this.state.cardModalOpen}
                  closeModal={this.closeModal}
                />
              </Card>
            );
          }

        return <div>{messagesDataNew}</div>;
   }
}
```

DetailModal.js

```
import React, { Component }from 'react';
import { Button, Card, Image, Header, Modal, Form, Input } from 'semantic-ui-react'

class DetailModal extends Component{

render(){

    return(
        <Modal open={this.props.cardModalOpen} onClose={()=>{this.props.closeModal()}} >
            <Modal.Header>Select a Photo</Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Content image>
                <Image wrapped size='medium' src='https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/large/rachel.png' />
                <Modal.Description>
                    <Header>Default Profile Image</Header>
                    <p>We've found the following gravatar image associated with your e-mail address.</p>
                    <p>Is it okay to use this photo?</p>
                </Modal.Description>
            </Modal.Content>
            <Button onClick={()=>{this.props.closeModal()}}>Close</Button>
        </Modal>
    )
  }

  }

export default DetailModal;
```

Here is a codesandbox with issue reproduced https://codesandbox.io/s/jjk7nw647y

Comment: replace We've with this html character &#39; for single quotes

Comment: @kosukeYoshimura, does the duplicate answer your question

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I followed the duplicated questions answer but still setState does not work

Comment: please, add more details or add working codesandbox/repl with the issue, here is similar codesandbox and it works fine https://codesandbox.io/s/lr3jrp4mmq

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/jjk7nw647y

This is my actual code. can u check? @amankkg

Comment: @KosukeYoshimura OK, then you need to update your question to include these details

Comment: added my suggestion as answer

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget bind your state handler functions:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.showCardModal=this.showCardModal.bind(this)
  this.closeModal =this.closeModal.bind(this)
}
```

Comment: this question has too many duplicates on Stackoverflow, consider marking such questions as duplicate.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri ok i am sorry

Answer (score 0):

In codesandbox you shared there is no clickable trigger-element for any of the modals. That's because of you are rendering an empty content of `Card`.

Here is my changes to your example https://codesandbox.io/s/l97n95n2om

The only difference is line #20 - I added a text `Some text` so your `Card` component has valid visible (and clickable) DOM element.